# How to Implement Two Way Syncing with RestKit

Tags: ios, iphone, restkit

I have an app that interacts with a web server's API via RestKit.  Users have a single account from which they can log in on both a browser client and their iPhone.  In both places, they can make changes to their data by adding objects, deleting objects, and editing objects.  How do I implement a way to sync all user additions, edits, and deletes by both pushing changes to the server and receiving changes from the server? Right now I have a hacky way of comparing Modification Dates on all objects, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Modification dates as a process is fine. Are you using RestKit to do the deletions? Do you have a particular issue with your approach?

Comment: Thanks Wain, it just seems like a lot of work is done that should be able to be reduced.  For example, if a user has 1000 objects, the iOS app needs to ask the server to send all 1000 objects, compare mod dates for each object, and then selectively decide which ones to keep.  If a user only made 1 change, it seems like there should be an easier way to manage it.

Comment: Well, that's really an issue with the server API design...